# Prevent XSS in NodeJS API output

Tags: node.js, api, xss

I'm familiar with using templates in NodeJS like EJS to escape data for an HTML context.

However what would be the recommended way to safely output from an API? Given the intended usage is not known, it couldn't be escaped using HTML encoding.

Since I'm currently basically just doing `res.json({})` for the output.

I'm thinking while some fields of incoming data can be validated (like 'email'), other fields that are more vague (like 'description') could contain any of the characters someone might use for XSS. Like < and ;. The options on OWASP seem limited https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Nodejs_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html Like this, but it was last updated 7 years ago https://github.com/ESAPI/node-esapi

Is it up to the recipient to handle? So if someone sends "alert(0);" as their description, I allow it through, as that is a valid JSON {"description":"alert(0);"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone wants to send `<script>tweet(document.cookie)</script>` in a description let them do so. They may have perfectly valid and legitimate reasons to do that. Perhaps they're writing an article about security and this is just an example of an XSS attack.

This isn't a threat to your database but to your web pages.

Security is neither a server-only nor a client-only job. It's a bit of both and the way you mitigate threats depends on the context.

When writing to a database, it's not XSS you have to worry about but things like SQL injection for example.

XSS is a threat for web applications and the way to mitigate that threat is to properly encode and/or escape any user-controlled input before it gets into the DOM.